# Mute Phone with exception

Tags: android

Is it possible to mute the device, but allow sounds & notifications from the app running?

Can you make an exception for the `RINGER_MODE_SILENT` [state](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29) (for one specific app)?

Comment: block notification for all those apps.

Comment: @Vishwesh Jainkuniya How would I do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html